# How does leaving the neutral line not connected to device lead to burn it?

Tags: neutral

When an air conditioner (inverter AC) connected to the source 220V/50 Hz the circuit breaker became off and each time I tried to make CB on it returned to off directly.

After the maintenance center checked the AC control board they told me some components like capacitor and diode burned also the inverter board has some components burned. The reason for this problem was the neutral line not connected to AC as they told me.

I checked the neutral wire connected to the AC and it was not connected on the distribution board.

Could someone explain how leaving the neutral line not connected lead to burn the device board.

Comment: How many live wires are feeding the AC? Can you [edit] your question to add in the link to the user manual?

Comment: Do you believe that a maintenance engineer will be able to say this. Or, is it more possible that he found that the neutral was disconnected and blamed that for your circuit woes.

Comment: We would have to see the schematics. If they are not available, it would be difficult to understand why the circuit broke if neutral was unconnected, if it ever was the cause.

Comment: *3 wires, I cant find the user manual for the AC

*the maintenance technician only tell me the neutral was the problem and he didn't have enough time explain how.

*Sorry i cant found any schematic for the AC 
 
thank you all

Comment: Vote to close, then, I'm afraid. The question is unanswerable in its current version.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the load is three phase and not perfectly balanced at either the fundamental or a harmonic then leaving the neutral disconnected will allow the phase - neutral voltage to change from the normal value, possibly ending up at almost the full phase-phase value.
Small loads like control electronics are often powered between one phase and neutral, so a missing neutral can cause these circuits to be exposed to excess voltage.

This is a somewhat popular way to let the smoke out of three phase systems.

Comment: 220V 50Hz is probably a single phase device unless it's in the right part of Japan